# Как сделать юзеру статус оффлайн на сайте, когда он ушел с него?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

С пустого места этот вопрос не возник, с помощью функции

```
$(window).unload(function(){

   $.post( 'do.php', { user: $name, status: 'off' } );

});
```

Я делаю пост к файлу do.php, который в свою очередь обновляет status у юзера в базе данных, было "on", стало "off", все это довольно таки просто выглядит, но! Куда же без "но"? Оно не срабатывает!!! А если и срабатывает, то раз через трое в лучшем случае.

Вопрос как сделать более точное определение когда юзер закрыл сайт (окно/браузер)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что поскольку ajax-запросы в jQuery по умолчанию асинхронны, то при отправке такого запроса по событию `unload`, он просто не успевает выполнится. Как только `handler` возвращает управление, браузер тут же закрывает вкладку не дожидаясь выполнения никаких ajax-запросов.

Что бы гарантировать выполнение ajax, необходимо отправлять запрос синхронно:

```
$.ajax('do.php', {async: false, data: { user: $name, status: 'off' }});
```

В этом случае вызов `$.ajax` будет заблокирован до тех пор, пока не придет ответ от сервера.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov - мысль верная, но и это не спасет от выключенного света :)

Comment: Разумеется, от выключения света спасет timeout. Но

> Я не могу 10-15 мин ждать, мне нужно так чтобы если юзер ушел, то все это сразу заметили, как в чатах.

это решит в 99.9% случаев. Чего не удастся сделать одним лишь timeout'ом.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, лучше этот запрос отправить асинхронно. Для закрываемой страницы получение ответа от сервера уже не важно. А, вот на сервер, сигнал ухода в оффлайн уйдет. Главное, чтобы серверный скрипт отработал до конца не взирая на то что клиент отключился (`ignore_user_abort()`).

Comment: @KiTE, нет никакой гарантии, что запрос хотя бы уйти успеет. Это может гарантировать только синхронный запрос. А что бы не ждать пока запрос обработается, лучше воспользоваться [`fastcgi_finish_request()`](http://php-fpm.org/wiki/Features#fastcgi_finish_request.28.29).

Answer (score 6):

Здесь нужно комплексное решения. Как верно заметил [[@sercxjo](/users/130/sercxjo)](/users/130/sercxjo), обработка ухода с сайта - не панацея.

Когда страница загрузилась, запускаем таймер, который через определенные промежутки времени  аяксом отправляет на сервер информацию о присутствии. Сервер в свою очередь получает запрос и фиксирует время последнего обращения. Дальше, чтобы выяснить присутствует пользователь или нет, серверу достаточно рассчитать интервал между временем последнего обращения по таймеру и текущим моментом. Если этот интервал превышает интервал клиентского таймера, значит аякс-запросов от браузера больше не поступает и пользователь ушел.

Чем чаще браузер будет отправлять такие запросы, тем точнее сервер будет знать о том, кто присутствует, а кто - нет. Но, при этом, частые обращения повышают нагрузку на сервер.  Поэтому оптимальный интервал опроса нужно расчитать исходя из предполагаемого кол-ва онлайн-пользователей, вычислительной мощности сервера и здравого смысла. К примеру, зачем  дергать сервак каждые 5 секунд если и 2-5 минут не критичны. Расчет типа: `100 онлайн-пользователей / интервал в 5 сек. = дают среднюю нагрузку 20 запросов в секунду`.

Плюс, на обработку ухода со страницы можно повесить отправку аякс-запроса с информацией о том, что пользователь ушел. Если это событие сработает, то сервер будет знать точный момент ухода.

При большом кол-ве обращений с информацией о присутствии стоит задуматься о методах хранения этой инфы на сервере. Чтобы каждое обращения не дергало каждый раз серверные винты можно использовать memcached или MySQL-таблицу с типом HEAP. Особенность HEAP-таблиц в том, что они держат свое содержимое в оперативе и не пишут его на винт, а для информации о присутствии этого вполне достаточно.

Как-то так...

**UPD:** Если развивать мысль дальше, то можно проработать систему с автоматической балансировкой нагрузки на сервер. Например, в серверный скрипт зашиваем константу: обрабатывать не более 20-ти запросов в секунду. Тогда, в ответ на аякс-запрос от клиента, можно отправлять ему рекомендуемый интервал для следующего обращения от него. Сервер знает текущее кол-во онлайн-клиентов (например 300 шт.), сервер знает константу 20-ть запросов в секунду. В момент очередного запроса от клиента делается нехитрый расчет `300 шт. / 20 = 15 сек.`, и эти 15 сек. отправляются клиенту. А клиент, получив ответ, прописывает этот рекомендуемый интервал в свой таймер до следующего обращения.

Таким образом в моменты пиковой нагрузки сервер сам будет регулировать кол-во отправляемых запросов с информацией присутствия.

Answer (score 3):

Храните в БД время последнего обращения юзера к сайту. Сообщение о закрытии страницы может никогда не прийти, если компьютер завис, сеть пропала, ноутбук ушёл в спячку...

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    //тут уведомляем сервер об уходе пользователя удобным нам способом 
});
```

Сработает на закрытие страницы, переход на другую страницу. **НЕ** работает в опере.

Answer (score 0):

И правда, с помощью JS это дело лучше не делать. Ситуации могут быть разные: начиная от того, что пользователь "завис" и вплоть до того, что "умный" юзер отключил JavaScript в своем браузере. Это ответственное дело, а значит пользователю( а следовательно и JS`у ) ни в коем случае доверять нельзя! Здесь хорошо подходит PHP( или любой другой серверный язык ). В таком случае, алгоритм пингования юзера прост: заносятся данные о том, что пользователь online, далее каждые 10-15 минут проверяется, не обновлял ли пользователь страницу, если нет, то он в 99% случаях уже вышел( или "завис", как это принято называть )

Comment: Я не могу 10-15 мин ждать, мне нужно так чтобы если юзер ушел, то все это сразу заметили, как в чатах.

Comment: Вы можете организовать такую систему на JS, но если "особо умный" юзер поймет, что система эта висит на яваскрипте( что сделать нетрудно ), он будет действовать. И система полетит)

Comment: А не проще ли не делать каждые 15 минут изменение статуса, который может и не понадобится, а вычислять этот самый статус исходя из времени когда пользователь был последний раз и времени на которое нужно получить этот статус?

Comment: что за CRON? На хостинге как с ним обращаться, он вообще есть там?

Comment: @Asen, спокойно всё это на JS делается, в чём тут проблема с безопасностью, что такого пользователь может сделать?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, ну, в таком случае, вообще не будет нормально работать. Но вреда то не принесёт всё равно. Не думаю, что о людях, которые просто берут и вырубают JS, нужно заботиться, если это будет стоить дорого.

Comment: @Construct - да ну?. У пользователей включен JS, в вашем чате сидит пол Москвы и больше никого, допустим у всех рубануло свет. Ваше приложение будет утверждать что куча народа онлайн, когда на деле - онлайн будет = 0.

Теперь разовьем мысль - допустим такое случилось 5 раз в течении недели на протяжении месяца :)

Какой вообще тогда смысл писать логику? Можно тупо сделать

     echo mt_rand(100, 100500) . ' пользователей онлайн';


Основную работу в любом случае должен делать сервер

Comment: @AlexWindHope, а чем тут поможет CRON? CRON работает на стороне сервера. Откуда серверу знать кто в сети, а кто - нет, если клиенты об этом специально ничего серверу не сообщают? В этом случае последние актуальные состояния клиентов - это те, которые сервер может зафиксировать в момент выдачи страницы в браузер каждого.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, полностью поддерживаю !

---
@Construct, ответ на свой шестой коммент был и в моем ответе, но спасибо @AlexWindHope, который ткнул вас носом в нужное место)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, ну-ну, раз ты предлагаешь такой супер-вариант, раскрой его суть в ответе. А, заодно, расскажи как ты будешь определять отвалившихся клиентов зная только `online=1`. Не, можно конечно очередной итерацией крона гасить всех, у кого `online=1` не обращая внимание на то, что один загрузил страницу две минуты назад а другой - секунду назад. . И там-же расскажи для кого твой CRON будет регулярно дергать скрипты в периоды нулевой посещаемости сайта.> для адекватного решения этой задачи однозначно нужен сервер. Ржунимагу, кто бы говорил про капитана.

Comment: А почему мой комментарий удалили? Некрасиво, ребята.  
Тот вариант, что описал KiTE - подходит для большинства случаев, и я вижу как он отлично работает на практике, про это я и говорил. Пускай там у всех свет отрубит - всё равно всё будет работать.

Answer (score -1):

Собрать все события-эвенты в кучу, разнести по исполняемым файлам и повесить все файлы на крон без всяких аяксов.